# PHP Why is this returning a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here's my code:

```
 foreach ($states as $staterow) {
            $state_set[] = array ('id' =>$staterow['id'],
                                      'st' =>$staterow['st'],
                                          'state' =>$staterow['state']);                          
        }

    foreach ($showresult as $display) {

        $display_result[] = array ( 'id' => $display['id'],
                        'name' => $display['name'],
                        'club_email' => $display['club_email'],
                        'description' => $display['description'],
                        'city' => $display['city'],
                        'state' => $display['state'],
                        'url' => $display['url'],
                        'facebook' => $display['facebook']);
                         unset($dispay_result); 

        $statearray[] = array ( 'state' => $display['state'] ); 
        }

    foreach ($statearray as $display) {
        $letterprocess[] = substr($display['state'], 0, 1);     
        }


    foreach ($fulllist as $x => $x_value) { 

        foreach ($letterprocess as $y => $y_value) {

            IF ($x_value == $y_value) {

                $true[] = array ($x_value); 
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($true);
```

Why is $true coming out as a multidimensional array? Why would it not come out as a simple array. If I echo $x_value inside the loop it is a variable, not an array.

Here's the var_dump:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "C"
  }
  [2]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "C"
  }
  [3]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "I"
  }
  [4]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "I"
  }
  [5]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "M"
  }
  [6]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "M"
  }
  [7]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "M"
  }
  [8]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "M"
  }
  [9]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "M"
  }
  [10]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "N"
  }
  [11]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(1) "V"
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you wrap the values into an array: `array ($x_value)`

Comment: Okay, so how do I do it so that it returns a simple array?

Comment: Just use the simple value: `$true[] = $x_value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$true[] = $x_value;
```

is what you're after.

In using

```
$true[] = array ($x_value);
```

you're explicitly casting `$x_value` into an array (`array ($x_value)`), and then adding that array to your `$true` array to give yourself an array of arrays